# Can Scala reflection get you the list of type aliases defined in a class?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

The situation I'm facing is one where I need to instantiate a class by name, but that class is actually a scala type alias defined in an object (a package object actually).  I have figured out many piece of what I need for this, but I can't find a way to introspect the object to get the type aliases.

Specifically, I have the string "Foo.MyString" and I want to instantiate an instance of that based on the following definition.

```
object Foo {
   type MyString = String
}
```

I can use `runtimeMirror.staticModule` to get the symbol, and then `runtimeMirror.reflectModule`, but I can't find any way to then resolve the type alias name of "MyString".

To get the methods or fields of Foo I can drop down to Java introspection with module.instance.getClass, but Java obviously doesn't have a way to get the type aliases.

I've also tried using Symbols, but that just let's you get the owner of a symbol, not the 'owned' symbol.

Comment: @texasbruce Sorry, regarding Scala reflection, I guess, you're wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @texasbruce Scala reflection can see not only class-based things from Java world but also information persisted in Scala signatures (ScalaSig, kind of comments in bytecode).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
typeOf[Foo.type].decl(TypeName("MyString")).asType.toType.dealias // String
typeOf[Foo.type].decl(TypeName("MyString")).typeSignature.dealias // String
```

or

```
val moduleSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticModule("pckg.App.Foo")
moduleSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TypeName("MyString")).asType.toType.dealias // String
moduleSymbol.typeSignature.decl(TypeName("MyString")).typeSignature.dealias // String
```

For the list of all type members see `.decls` instead of individual `.decl(...)`. You can filter the list

```
typeOf[Foo.type].decls.filter(_.isType)
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the `typeSignature` call I was missing!  As a bit of extra info for anyone trying to do this on a Scala package object, the answer is   `val moduleSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticModule("ai.closedloop.foo.package")`